# Linux mail client that can trigger a PHP script to parse email received

Tags: centos, email, php

Is there any simple text-based mail client that I could use that could trigger a PHP script to parse mails received from the users?

I have a PHP application that sends email out to users and it would be nice if the application can parse the reply from users and store them into the database.

I'm using Centos 6 with Postfix and PHP sends email out using PHPMailer. No X Window System installed.

Comment: You may want to migrate this to http://stackoverflow.com, as it is more programming than unix/linux oriented.

Comment: I'm not really sure about the OS but what I would like to do is have a mail client to trigger a PHP script that will parse email reply whenever it receive mail. Or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, as you refer to a text-based mail client and a PHP application and then specify that "the application" (i.e. your PHP application) to store email (or data extracted from that) in a  database.

You can and probably should separate your sending application from your response processing application. The response processing can be done by calling any script from procmail, for that you need a .procmailrc file in the home directory of the receiving user that has the following:

```
:0
* ^Subject:.*[response-email]
| /path/to/your_script
```

You can leave out the Subject line if you want all mails to that email address processed, or use different selection criteria.

As for `your_script` I don't know of any commandline mail clients that directly put your material in a database. Since you probably should test the response anyway (if not to extract some extra database fields, at least to throw away spam) you might want to write `your_script` in PHP using [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse) to parse its content and store it in your database.
(Of course you can use other languages you are familiar with for this purpose as well).

If you are using postfix to receive emails on the machine this script runs on, make sure to call `procmail` in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
```

Comment: Hi anthon, I'm not sure how Centos works but I'm looking for a mail client that could trigger a PHP script that could trigger a PHP script to parse email reply whenever a mail is received. Can this be done in Linux? Sorry for the terrible English. I think it's confusing myself.

Comment: Youd don't need a mail client for that. Either your CentOS system receives the mail directly, or you pick it up via `fetchmail` and forward it to the user with the `.procmailrc` (I do exactly that on my workstation). procmail will trigger your PHP script.

Comment: If you want to use literal square brackets in a regex, you have to backslash-escape them -- `\[response-email\]`

Answer (score 2):

... Okay, I'm going to take a few steps back and explain some things about how email works under the hood, because judging by your questions in comments part of your problem with this question is that you don't understand how things work, which in turn is causing misconceptions as to what you need to do to accomplish what you want.

First off, a few basic terms:

- A Mail User Agent (MUA) is what you'd call a "mail client". Its purpose is to allow a user to send emails, or retrieve them from a mailbox and read them. Technically speaking, when your PHP script sends an email it's acting as an MUA.
- A Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) is solely concerned with  the business of moving email from one place to another. Nowadays, this generally includes making sure the email it gets handed is something it *should* pass on before doing so, but that's outside the scope for now. Think of it as a post office.
- A Mail Delivery Agent (MDA) serves as the endpoint of a pipeline; when an MTA determines that a particular email should be delivered locally, it calls on the MDA to handle things.

When you send an email, what happens is as follows:

1. The MUA generates the email, either via script or from user input, makes sure it's encapsulated properly as per international standards (the equivalent of writing the address in the proper place and adding the right amount of stamps) and hands it off to its configured MTA. Virtually all UNIX variants outside of *really* tiny embedded systems will have a local MTA running, specifically so that anything that needs to send email will have a way to do so without having to speak SMTP.
2. The MTA receives the message and, after making sure it's *supposed* to handle the message, looks at the destination address and decides what to do with it. If it's not meant to be handled locally, it will pass the message on to another MTA that, as far as it knows, is the appropriate place to send that particular message.
3. Depending on the actual setup, step 2 can repeat a few times -- for instance, local machine -> sender ISP's smarthost for outgoing mail -> receiver ISP's Anti-virus/Anti-spam filter -> ISP's primary incoming mail server.
4. Ultimately, assuming things are configured properly, the loop in step 3 will terminate at an MTA that is either capable of locally delivering the email, or authoritatively tell the sender that their mail won't be accepted.
5. This final MTA will hand the email over to the specified MDA, which will then process actual delivery. This is *usually* done by dropping it into the recipient's mailbox but can be configured to be almost anything.

What you're asking for is accomplished at step 5; what you want to do is set up a delivery rule for that particular email address to, rather than deliver it into a mailbox for reading by humans, pipe the email into a local program (which does not need to be that particular PHP script, or indeed *any* PHP script -- as long as it's executable) which will in turn parse the email input and use it to fill out an entry in a database.

[Anthon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80860/4949) covers the most expedient way to set up the pipe, assuming you have the ability to add additional email addresses and associated users on your mail server. If you don't, you'll need to be more creative but without more information as to the arrangements between you, your ISP, and the domain name of your website, we can't offer much more advice than this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are after a PHP extension/class:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php

http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get if you want to parse it in your PHP-application or just on the server. Both variants are possible without using any mail-client.

1) Bash/SH or another scripting language. Something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

MyUSER="SET-MYSQL-USER-NAME"
MyPASS="SET-PASSWORD"
MyHOST="localhost"
MyDB="SET-DB"

for mFile in `grep -iR 'WHAT TO FIND???' .`
do
  # here do something with your e-mail z.B:
  mysql -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS MyDB << EOF
      insert into ...
      values ...;
  EOF
done
```

2) Or parser on the application side (in PHP), which is pretty simple. Have a look at this library: https://github.com/plancake/official-library-php-email-parser

Comment: But without a mail client, how would I be able to receive mail files?

Comment: Postfix server is responsible for that. Look at [link](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix), in case you havn't configured it yet.